# Sending html form controls in email through sqlserver

Tags: html, sql-server, outlook-2010

I am trying to send an email, from sqlserver, that has html form elements like textfields and buttons.

Here is my script

```
Declare @Body varchar(max)

set @Body = '<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/Email_test/TestServlet.do" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="update"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
'

exec sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'test_profile',
@recipients='me@example.com',
@subject = 'This is a test form',
@body = @Body,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

The above script works fine and sends an email to the intended recipient with one problem.
The form elements are not present in the mail and a message is displayed at the very top of the mail that says "if the message of this mail is not displayed properly click here to open it in a web browser".

I am using microsoft outlook 2010.

Is there a way to make these form elements render in the mail itself, instead of going to the browser..?

Comment: The receiver's email client would need to be setup to render html, which isn't always the case.

Comment: the arrangements can be made to make the receiver's email client to render html. Would you explain how to set this up..?

Comment: It appears Outlook is set to use html by default:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-the-message-format-to-html-rich-text-or-plain-text-HP001232996.aspx.  Assuming other installs are similar to your own, try sending the test emails to your address and see how they appear.  If the message shows all the tags, you'll need to configure it to use html by default.

Comment: as i have mentioned in my question, the test mail renders fine except for the form elements.

Comment: Apparently older versions of outlook may strip the form elements out:  http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it is evident that outlook mail client doesn't support the form tags and other elements like a button or textbox. But the form element and other input elements work when you use the online version of outlook OWA.

But in OWA also scripts won't get executed. In the desktop version, there will be an option to view the message in the web browser, which will render everything fine just like a web page.

As pointed out by others, there appears to be some serious levels of security issues. For instance, there is no way to authenticate if the form is submitted by the intended recipient. Anybody with access to the html code can just fill it and submit it as there is no method to authenticate the submitter.

Microsoft Infopath or outlook's custom forms can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML form tag is not supported in Outlook from 2007, including in Outlook 2010. Its considered a security risk.

Actually its not a SQL-Server issue, its a email client issue. As you can see in the image below, lots of clients don't support the form tag.

[image]

image from this url: http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/